# What sub-genre of jazz is Dondi by Ed Motta?

Tags: identify-this-genre, jazz

To which sub-genre of jazz belongs Ed Motta’s [*Dondi*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXOxpsJB_8E)?

Is it pop jazz? Smooth jazz? Or anything else?

Comment: It's probably more in the side of soul, funk, and r&b. Doesn't sound very jazzy to me.

Comment: There is only two genres in music: Good music and Bad Music. Everything in between is indexation to cd stores and there is no meaning to us listeners.

Answer (score 2):

This is **jazz-funk**, a combination of a laid-back jazz sensibility with a funk instrumentation and groove.  It's quite distant from traditional jazz.

> Jazz-funk is a subgenre of jazz music characterized by a strong back beat (groove), electrified sounds and an early prevalence of analog synthesizers. The integration of funk, soul, and R&B music and styles into jazz resulted in the creation of a genre whose spectrum is quite wide and ranges from strong jazz improvisation to soul, funk or disco with jazz arrangements, jazz riffs, and jazz solos, and sometimes soul vocals.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazz-funk

Compare these classic examples of the genre: [Mizell Brothers Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dyf2naIPD9g&list=PLxdOFfQtAfT06g5rdSfi3PLU-71RfVl8l), [Herbie Hancock - Head Hunters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3m3qOD-hhrQ)

Answer (score 1):

I'd describe it more as **[jazz-rock](http://www.allmusic.com/subgenre/jazz-rock-ma0000012014) à la [Steely Dan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steely_Dan), combined with soul and MPB** (Música popular brasileira). It's certainly jazz-tinged rather than jazz.